# Elasticsearch match_pharse query but promote results that doesn't have any words before and after text

Tags: elasticsearch

I need an Elasticsearch Query similar to this one but promote results that don't have any words before and after it:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_pharse": {
            "title": "brown fox"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I have indexed data like this:

```
{"title":"brown Fox"}
{"title":"Brown and brave fox"}
{"title":"It's brown fox"}
{"title":"brave fox on tree"}
{"title":"no related result"}
```

My result should be:

```
{"title":"brown Fox"}
{"title":"It's brown fox"}
{"title":"Brown and brave fox"}
```

The important thing about my result is the items without any extra words should always appear first, but I don't know why I have some of them in a lower score.

I think I should be using `should` in my query to promote my results but I don't know what to write inside of it to promote results without any extra words before and after of text to top.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It works on my sample dummy data that I created to check. Maybe the ES already works this way.

Comment: By default smaller  fields are scored higher. So result should be in line with your expectation.